# How do I access and modify an image in an HTML page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML page has an image with id img. The idea is that by clicking first, previous, or next, the user can navigate through a set of images. How do I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried any of the 10000 image gallery plugins available? [Google search results](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?hl=en&btnG=Google+Search#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=14&gs_id=67&xhr=t&q=jquery+image+gallery&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jquery+image+g&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4f9c96331412778a&biw=1541&bih=884)

Comment: I'm new to this, I'm trying to work out javascript by example.

Comment: Then add the world tutorial onto the end of your search query. Again, I'm sure there's hundreds of image gallery tutorials out there :)

Comment: Did none of these answers provide you with a solution??  If it did, please accept the answer you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start for you:

```
<script>
  var imgs = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"]; // copy images to the same dir
  var index = 0;
</script>
<img src="img1.png" onclick="this.src=imgs[++index%imgs.length]"/>
```

click the image to slide.

If you need buttons, see this example:

```
  <img id="clicker" src="img1.png"/>
  <a href="#" onclick="prev(); return false;">Prev</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="first(); return false;">First</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="last(); return false;">Last</a>
<script>
  var imgs = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"];
  var index = 0;
  var clicker = document.getElementById("clicker");
  function prev() { clicker.src = imgs[--index%imgs.length]; }
  function next() { clicker.src = imgs[++index%imgs.length]; }
  function first() { clicker.src = imgs[index=0]; }
  function last() { clicker.src = imgs[index=imgs.length-1]; }
</script>
```

The `return false` means that default action on click (follow the link) is supressed. Javascript can access elements i.e. using `id` (see `clicker` here). Once you get comfortable with this and you start to solve browser compatibility problems, it is good idea to continue with jQuery (as the other suggests), MooTools or other framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery!

```
var myImg = $("#myimg");
$("#next").click(function(){
    var id = myImg.attr("data-id") + 1;
    myImg.attr("src", "image"+id+".jpg");
});
$("#prev").click(function(){
    var id = myImg.attr("data-id") -1;
    myImg.attr("src", "image"+id+".jpg");
});
```

HTML:

```
<img id="myimg" src="image1.jpg" data-id="1">
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a><br>
<a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a><br>
```

This is a very dummy example. There are numerous slideshow plugins out there!

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to start with some framework instead of plain javascript.

Comment: That's right. But sooner or later if his website grows he will find a framework very useful to make coding much easier.

Comment: Sooner or later, but not in this stage: I often see big balls of jQuery mud which can be solved in a very easy way if they only knew plain javascript. And your example can be easily rewritten to plain javascript. Never mind.

Comment: It doesn't plan on growing, it's just a practice website to get comfy with javascript.

Comment: Still it's good idea to get to know jQuery as well. You might save a lot of time when it comes to having cross browser support. Otherwise @graphicdivine's answer is enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

No need jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = function() {
    var imageSrcs= ['1.jpeg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];
    var index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('img');

    var previous = document.getElementById('previous');
        previous.onclick = function() {
            index -= 1;
            if(index < 0) index = imageSrcs.length - 1;
            image.src = imageSrcs[index];
        }

    var next = document.getElementById('next');
        next.onclick = function() {
            index += 1;
            if(index == imageSrcs.length) index = 0;
            image.src = imageSrcs[index]; 
        }

 }
</script>
```

And html:

```
<img src='1.jpeg' id='img'>
<div>
    <span id='previous'>Previous</span>
    <span id='next'>Next</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** need a library for this. Something like this will change the image url, where "theImg" is the `id` of the image:

```
document.getElementById("theImg").src = "newUrl.png";
```

To do it without explicit `id`s, this will change the url where `i` is the index of the image:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].src = "newUrl.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested):

LOAD JQUERY:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var lst_src = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.png', 'img3.gif'];
  $('a', '#nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src_current = $('#img').attr('src');
    var index = lst_src.indexOf(src_current);
    var len = lst_src.length;
    var action = $(this).attr('class');
    switch ($action) {
      case 'previous' : var i = index - 1;
                        if (i < 0) src_current = lst_src[len + i];
                        else src_current = lst_src[i];
                        break;
      case 'next'     : var i = index + 1;
                        if (i > len) src_current = lst_src[i - len];
                        else src_current = lst_src[i];
                        break;
      case 'first'    : src_current = lst_src[0];
                        break;
      case 'last'     : src_current = lst_src[len - 1];
                        break;
     }
     $('#img').attr('src', src_current);
  });
</script>
```

HTML: Use the class of a link to denote the required action:

```
<img id='img' src='img1.jpg'>

<p id='nav'>
  <a href='' class='first'>&larr;&larr;First</a>
  <a href='' class='previous'>&larr;Previous</a>
  <a href='' class='next'>Next&rarr;</a>
  <a href='' class='last'>Last&rarr;$rarr;</a>
</p>
```